# What are the different version of Eclipse for Java EE/ IBM RSA

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, rational-rsa

Which is the latest version to work on with Java EE

- Eclipse - Tomcat combination ?
- IBM RSA - WebSphere combination ?

Comment: Please make sure you tag correctly. In this case the RSA tag should not be used for Rationale, but for the RSA cryptographic algorithm - something entirely different.

Answer (score 0):

### 1. **Eclipse** is an integrated development environment (IDE).

It contains

- A base work-space
- An extensible plug-in system for customizing the environment.

Version 3 includes

- Helios
- Indigo
- Juno

Version 4 includes

- Kepler
- **Luna** **[latest of of this writing]**
- [Mars] is yet to come in 2015

### 2.**Tomcat - Application Server**

Apache Tomcat (or simply Tomcat, formerly also Jakarta Tomcat) is an open source web server and servlet container developed by the Apache Software Foundation (ASF).

```
**Current stable version - 8.0.12** [ as of this writing]
```

I prefer to use Tomcat 7 and above for full functionality

### 3.**Rational Software Architect** is built on the Eclipse

- It includes capabilities focused on architectural code analysis
- C++
- model-driven development (MDD) with the UML for creating applications and web services.

Use a version above **V 7.0.0.3: Released July 2007** as it started the support for  asynchronous web services from this version

### 4.**IBM WebSphere**

IBM has shipped several versions and editions of WebSphere Application Server.

WebSphere version

**||--8.5.5--||--8.5--||--8.0--||--7.0--||--6.1--||--6.0--||--5.1--||--5.0--||--4.0--||--3.5--||**

I personally prefer to use 6.1 and above version as they fully support web services which has become an integral part of the industry.

This is while little tricky to choose the application server. Refer to the IBM documentation to choose the appropriate server for your project specific need.

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_6.1.0/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/info/aes/ae/rovr_specs.html?cp=SSEQTP_6.1.0%2F1-0-0-1